# What is the correct way to validate a signed word document?

Tags: .net, powershell, ms-word, digital-signature, openxml-sdk

According to ["The Digital Signing Framework of the Open Packaging Conventions"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905326.aspx), a .docx file is essentially a zip file of various "parts", and signing a .docx is means including signatures of some subset of those parts in the .docx container.  But there's no mention of what subset of parts constitutes a valid signature.  There's a section describing the .XPS "Application Signing Policy", but there's no equivalent for .DOCX.  The Packaging API tells me which parts are signed and whether their signature is valid, but it seems that it's up to the programmer to ensure that all the parts that need to be signed are in the signed list.  The linked document just says:

> Applications using package-based formats define their own policies as
>   part of the Signing Framework. The policy is determined by the element
>   types and workflow requirements of the format.

How do I know what the correct policy is for Word documents?

For example, signing a simple Word document using Word 2013 and using the Packaging API to enumerate the signed parts shows that not all the Parts are signed.  In particular, `/docProps/core.xml` (which appears to contain the document "owner") is not signed:

```
Add-Type -Assembly WindowsBase
$f = "My Signed File.docx"
$p = [System.IO.Packaging.Package]::Open($f)
$dsm = [System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignatureManager]::new($p)
$p.GetParts() | ForEach-Object {$_.Uri.ToString()}
$dsm.Signatures | ForEach-Object {$_.SignedParts} | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString()}
```

Prints (all parts):

```
/docProps/app.xml
/docProps/core.xml
/word/document.xml
/word/fontTable.xml
/word/settings.xml
/word/styles.xml
/word/theme/theme1.xml
/word/webSettings.xml
/word/_rels/document.xml.rels
/_rels/.rels
/_xmlsignatures/origin.sigs
/_xmlsignatures/sig1.xml
/_xmlsignatures/_rels/origin.sigs.rels
```

And (signed parts):

```
/word/document.xml
/word/fontTable.xml
/word/settings.xml
/word/styles.xml
/word/theme/theme1.xml
/word/webSettings.xml
```

Comment: Metadata are indeed not signed as they are considered to not be part of the document's content (afaik). I don't know about any documentation that describes what parts exactly Word includes in a signature. However, if you only need to validate the signature that should not matter, as all you need to know is included in the signature parts. You can start from there and then validate the XAdES signature.

Comment: I don't agree - I think that it does matter which parts Word needs to include.  A signature over, say, everything but `/word/document.xml` would validate correctly but be worthless, since a malicious party could then change the document text without invalidating the signature.

Comment: In fact, it seems that there is no explicit (publicly documented) signing policy. The `SignaturePolicyIdentifier` is set to `SignaturePolicyImplied`. According to the [XAdES specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/#Syntax_for_XAdES_The_SignaturePolicyIdentifier_element) this can be used *“when the signature policy can be unambiguously derived from the semantics of the type of data object(s) being signed, and some other information”*. I guess in this case  the semantics can be derived from the Open XML specification?

Comment: Part 1 of the ECMA Open XML specification is 5029 pages.  There are four parts.

Comment: That said - the structure isn't that bad.  There are parts and relationships, and the packaging API will tell me which which parts and which relationships are signed, so I can traverse the graph starting at "/word/document.xml" and ensure that everything I see is in the signature.  That seems reasonable to me - but given that this is ultimately a security issue... yikes.

Comment: The reason that digital signature support is not as elaborate as it could be is likely that the Office file formats are first and foremost a format for editing documents – and not for storing unmodifiable / archivable versions of documents with a well-defined visual representation. Imho, PDF/A is much better suited for being digitally signed, e.g. using a PAdES signature.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as far as this..

> 'How do I know what the correct policy is for Word documents?'

Digital signatures are not really polices in the since of real DLP/ IP tools deliver. They are just mostly used identity attributes.
If you are looking at real polices, the that is what AD RMS / Azure Information Protection solutions, etc. are for.

Here are notes I have on this digital signature topic, well relative to validation.

All this signing stuff is via the Microsoft CAPI NG API.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376214(v=vs.85).aspx

In virtually every case I have seen, this will involve certificates, self-signed, domain issued or external 3rdP cert.

When you open a signed doc in Word, you'll see the 'Signatures' button (red ribbon) in the UI, which translates into the fact the it is in the Word DOM. So, the prudent approach would be to navigate the DOM to see where that is for validation.

> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-digital-signature-and-certificate-details-76BA00CB-1E58-42AA-8717-0CAEE76BB3CF

Now, all that being said, meaning, all the props you are looking at. You can look at signature Boolean evidence directly.

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx

```
sigcheck.exe -a -u -e
```

You can leverage the signtool.exe

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764.aspx
>
> ```
> # sign - Digitally signs files.
> # verify - Verifies the digital signature of files.
>
> signtool verify /pa myfile.exe
> if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 echo This file is not signed.
>
> # verbose out put, add a '/v' after '/pa'.
> ```

PoSH can look at signature of files using the below cmdlet vs mining doc properties. However, this is not looking at all these properties, just the sig.

```
 Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'C:\windows\explorer.exe'
```

You can of course you .NET retrieve the cert that signed the file, thus getting the owner.